# Modifying nested data in clojure

Tags: clojure, maps

How can I manipulate a nested data structure? 
I have a list of this kind

```
[["first_string" {:one 1 :two 2}]
["second_string" {:three 3 :four 4}]
["third_string" {:five 5 :six 6}]
["fourth_string" {:seven 7 :eight 8}]]
```

And I need to change it to this form:

```
[["first_string" 1]
["second_string" 3]
["third_string" 5]
["fourth_string" 7]]
```

Essentially, I want only the first element of each of the inner vectors first key of the map

Comment: Write a function transforming `["first_string" {:one 1 :two 2}]` to `["first_string" 1]`, and then map it over your input list.

Comment: Be careful about getting elements from an associative structure like a hashmap via an index. No guarantee the first element in will be the first element out. Also lookup the following functions map, first, second rest, juxt, and comp.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining a function that operates on a single entry in the vector and then `map` over it:

```
(defn manipulate-nested
        [entry]
        [(first entry) (last (first (last entry)))])

(let [input [["first_string" {:one 1 :two 2}]
             ["second_string" {:three 3 :four 4}]
             ["third_string" {:five 5 :six 6}]
             ["fourth_string" {:seven 7 :eight 8}]]]
  (into [] (map manipulate-nested input)))

;; [["first_string" 1] 
;;  ["second_string" 3]   
;;  ["third_string" 5]  
;;  ["fourth_string" 7]]
```

> I need to change it to this form

NB: Keep in mind that strictly speaking you're not *changing* (mutating) the original vector, but describing a modification of it.

Comment: Sorry for the novice question, I am used to loops in java programming and trying to learn clojure now

Comment: @Sagarika no apology needed! Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't get a reliable first key of a hash-map because hash-maps are an unsorted data structure and seqing them thus has no order guarantees.  So there is no first or second.

There is no way of numerically ordering the keywords `:one`, `:two`, `:three` without parsing their names which I leave as a separate problem.

Here is your problem reposed with ordered structures in place of the hash-maps:

```
(def data [["first_string" [[:one 1] [:two 2]]]
           ["second_string" [[:three 3] [:four 4]]]
           ["third_string" [[:five 5] [:six 6]]]
           ["fourth_string" [[:seven 7] [:eight 8]]]]
```

One typical and idiomatic solution is to extract from each vector in `data` independently via [map](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/map), using [destructuring](http://clojure.org/guides/destructuring) in the transformation functions binding vector to bind the desired nested elements and returning this extraction in a new vector:

```
(map (fn [[s [[_ n] _]]] [s n]) data)
```

The input data structure of your specific problem offers a way with less overhead by reusing the passed vector instead of constructing a new one in each step:

```
(map #(update % 1 (comp second first)) data)
```